# What justified that impetus was in proportion to speed and weight?

Tags: aristotle, momentum

I often see the claim that impetus, the ancestor of momentum, was understood to be proportional to speed and weight.

For example, Jean Buridan wrote:

> When a mover sets a body in motion he implants into it a certain
> impetus, that is, a certain force enabling a body to move in the
> direction in which the mover starts it, be it upwards, downwards,
> sidewards, or in a circle. **The implanted impetus increases in the same
> ratio as the velocity.** It is because of this impetus that a stone
> moves on after the thrower has ceased moving it. But because of the
> resistance of the air (and also because of the gravity of the stone)
> which strives to move it in the opposite direction to the motion
> caused by the impetus, the latter will weaken all the time. Therefore
> the motion of the stone will be gradually slower, and finally the
> impetus is so diminished or destroyed that the gravity of the stone
> prevails and moves the stone towards its natural place. In my opinion
> one can accept this explanation because the other explanations prove
> to be false whereas all phenomena agree with this one.

As seen above, the claim offers no evidence, anecdotes, reasoning, or geometry to support the establishment of the ratio -- it seems completely arbitrary.  For the same reason (or rather lack thereof), why not claim that impetus is proportional to the squares of the speeds or the squares of the weights?

Comment: Because Aristotle said so. Or rather he wrote that the speed attained is proportional to the force applied, and the impetus, being "impressed force" invented to fix his account of projectile motion, inherited the proportionality. Aristotle's arguments do not really establish proportionality of force/weight and speed either, see [Rovelli's reconstruction, p.3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4057#), but it is the simplest dependence consistent with his qualitative discussion. Scholastics were mostly concerned with qualitative explanations, so their mathematical statements should be taken loosely.